# How to display set of items in array after after some delay?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a chat application. 
I am getting all the chat history at once from an api and storing it in an array name $scope.channel
I am displaying these list of items present in an array using ng-repeat. What I want to do is display sets of data from array in some intervals. For example when user opens chat screen he/she should be able to see few chats/images. Then after some seconds mmore data will be loaded.

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Comment: Is there any server-side pagination logic for it?

Comment: @SajjadShahi No pagination in backend. I am getting all the data at once.

Comment: What about using `$timeout` service? Store your messages in another variable, initially fill `$scope.channel` with like 5 elements, then using `$timeout` push more data in it. see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: Is there a way to do that with ng-repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sajjad Shahi suggested you could use the `$timeout` service. Maybe something like the following. You can set the desired delay and chuck size. Use your `$scope.channel` array as `srcArray` and an empty array `yourArrayToDisplay` as `destArray`. Replace `channel` by `yourArrayToDisplay` in the `ng-repeat` directive. This should give you the desired result as far as I can follow.

```
var dalayedChunkHandler =  {
    chunkSize: 1,
    delay: 2000,
    timeout: null,
    srcArray: [],
    destArray: [],
    dalayedChunk: function(){
        var _this = this;

        var len = _this.destArray.length;
        Array.prototype.push.apply(_this.destArray,_this.srcArray.slice(len, len + _this.chunkSize));                    

        if(_this.srcArray.length > _this.destArray.length) _this.start();
    },
    start: function(){
        var _this = this;
        _this.timeout = $timeout(function(){_this.dalayedChunk.call(_this)}, _this.delay)
    }
};


$scope.yourArrayToDisplay = []; // use this array for ng-repeat
dalayedChunkHandler.destArray = $scope.yourArrayToDisplay;
dalayedChunkHandler.srcArray = $scope.chatHistoryArray; // the array you got
dalayedChunkHandler.start();
```